# How to change a color of a single row in the ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, listview, data-binding

I built WPF application that is linked to Entity Framework.

The program adds user details in to a list and all details are stored in a database. So whenever I close and reopen the application, the details that have been added previously are there.

The application has a feature to calculate the average module grade.

Here is a fragment of my code:

```
if (averageResult < 7 && averageResult > 5)
{
    student.Average_Grade = "F";
}
```

So if this condition is met, I also want the row turn red or a letter F to turn red.

I searched the internet but only thing i find is how to change it in a simple WPF application not linked to database.

So how do you change the color of a single row in the ListView if WPF application is linked to a database?

**UPDATE**

Ive tried this code:

```
 student.Average_Grade = "F" + new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

But instead of a single row is changes the color of a whole window

LISTVIEW XAML

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="studentListView" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="10,10,-10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>

                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="first_NameColumn" Width="80" Header="First Name">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Margin="-6,-1" Text="{Binding First_Name, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="last_NameColumn" Width="80" Header="Last Name">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Margin="-6,-1" Text="{Binding Last_Name, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="matric_NumberColumn" Width="80" Header="Matric Number">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Margin="-6,-1" Text="{Binding Matric_Number, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="component1_GradeColumn" Width="80" Header="Component 1 Grade" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Margin="6,-1,-6,-1" Text="{Binding Component1_Grade, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="component2_GradeColumn" Width="80" Header="Component 2 Grade">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Margin="-6,-1" Text="{Binding Component2_Grade, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="component3_GradeColumn" Width="80" Header="Component 3 Grade">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Margin="-6,-1" Text="{Binding Component3_Grade, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="average_GradeColumn" Width="80" Header="Average Grade">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Margin="-6,-1" Text="{Binding Average_Grade, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="edit">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Edit" Click="OnEdit"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="delete">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="Delete" Click="OnDelete" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="Control.VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Databases have nothing to do with it. [Use an ItemTemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8935831/424129). You'll need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your `Student` class as well, if you haven't already.

Comment: so according to you logic, I would have to go to Student class and do some modification to the Average Grade column aswell? Everything works fine for me, I just dont know how to change the color of that F

Comment: Can you share your xaml? I think you need a converter, it will test if the condition is met and return red color

Comment: If you want the `ListView` to update anything when you change the value of `student.Average_Grade`, then you need to notify the `ListView` when `Average_Grade` changes. `INotifyPropertyChanged` is how you do that.

Comment: Oh, but wait, is the Student class generated by Entity Framework? Then you definitely don't want to alter it. Let me look into that real quick.

Comment: yes it is. I did not have to change anything according to you suggestion, everything works like a clock. i need the right after after this statement: student.Average_Grade = "F";

Comment: Looks like using EF with WPF is a pain: [You can write viewmodel wrappers for the EF classes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14132400/424129), or you can [mess with the T4 template that generates the EF classes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25901189/424129). The T4 business sounds like it may turn ugly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment. Is the line turning red now?

Comment: Amine I doubt it has anything do to with xaml. I think its I just have to figure out the right code

Comment: If I understand, you want covert F to Red!!! it's a converter

Comment: I dont want to convert F to red. I want background of a row where F is to be red, or the letter F to change color from black to red

Comment: Yes, so you must use a converter. look at my answer

Comment: and if you want a complete answer, we need to see your xaml

Comment: how can I share my xaml ? is says the code is too long

Comment: you share only xaml of ListView

Comment: look at my answer and tell me if it's ok

Comment: It doesnt work, I think i need to know the imports for a program to recognize IValueConverter

Answer (score 0):

You can use a converter. Add a new class as bellow:

```
public class Converter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value.ToString() == "F")
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        else
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And in your xaml you add this:

```
<Window.Resources> // Or UserControl.Resources
    <local:Converter x:Key="converter"/> 
</Window.Resources>
```

And replace the ItemContainerStyle

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Average_Grade, Converter={StaticResource converter}}" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: which imports do you need ?

Comment: sorry, no such word as Foregroung. and Also I get an error message after I put <local:Converter x:Key="converter"/>  message is: "Converter not in the same namespace" even tho IT IS

Comment: @user3438350 did you put TargetType="ListViewItem" ?. the converter must be public and local must be declared as bellow : xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ApplicationName"

Comment: Once you've written a Style, why not toss the Converter (which is only giving him grief) and use a trigger?

Comment: i will check it our tomorrow, tell you if that works